# Twitter timeline embed is not working on website

Tags: twitter, embed, twitter-timeline

I am using embed code from https://publish.twitter.com/ to embed our Twitter timeline on a website but it's showing as blank. I checked the console and it showed no errors.

Could something be blocking Twitter from showing on the other website as embedded?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/XYZ?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by XYZ</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Twitter issue. The widget stopped working a few weeks back. It requires a fix from Twitter. However, if they take much longer I will be removing all feeds from all the websites I have this feed upon.

Comment: It seems problem has not been resolved when i embed it on other domains it works but it doesn't work with one particular domain.. so i am not sure if issue is due to twitter of something else which doesnt make sence to me

Answer (score 0):

You have to login to get the latest post using https://publish.twitter.com/